# How is Data masking price calculated in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-data-catalog, dynamic-data-masking

We run 2 queries from a table in 2 scenarios:

1. We run a query to create a table from selecting data of another table (ex: ABC), this table ABC has no any policy tags (data masking rules) on any columns:
   create table `project.dataset.ABC_NOT_MASKED` as select col1, col2 from `project.dataset.ABC`
2. We add a policy tag with data masking rule (Hash (SHA256)) on some columns for this ABC table and run a similar query:
   create table `project.dataset.ABC_MASKED` as select col1, col2 from `project.dataset.ABC`

These 2 queries resulted the same cost (even there are data masking policy on the columns or not). The bytes processed of these 2 queries are the same, about 99 GiB. According to https://cloud.google.com/dlp/pricing#inspection_and_transformation_pricing, we assumed that the query with data masking will have bigger cost.

Why is this? How is the billing calculated in data masking?

Comment: DLP has its own price list here: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/pricing

Comment: I checked the cost of the month, there is no any cost for DLP SKU (https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups/cloud-data-loss-prevention). It's strange if DLP has its own price

Comment: DLP is not involved when using BigQuery built in query support for transformations. This is entirely a BQ feature you are using.